# on click ajax result always updates last clicked element

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Consider the following code, if I click 3 links in a row, the last clicked "section" is updated 3 times, the first 2 remane the same. (assuming you click 3 links before the ajax finishes)

```html
<div><span class="show-records">click me</span></div>
<div><span class="show-records">click me</span></div>
<div><span class="show-records">click me</span></div>
```

```js
$('.show-records').on('click', function(e) {
    el = $(this).parent(); // get parent of clicked link
    $.ajax({
        url: "...",
        method: 'POST',
        data: $(this).data('data'),
        beforeSend: function() {
            el.html('<p style="margin-left: 24px;">loading <span class="loading-spinner"></span></p>'); // show a spinner
        },
        error: function() {
            alert("{{ 'unknown error'|trans({}, 'alerts') }}");
        }
    }).then(function(html) {
        el.html(html); // update html with table
    });
});
```

I can only assume it is because my `el` variable is being updated with each click, and "then" always uses the latest `el`

How can I isolate the parent element between each click event?

I have tried using `success` & `complete` functions inside `$.ajax` but `this` & `$(this)` are no longer the clicked element.

Comment: I'd make a function outside of the promise, and use .then() to invoke it to set the el.

Comment: Where is the `el` variable declared? If it isn't needed outside these functions then just rewrite `el =... ` as `let el = ... `

Comment: `el = $(this).parent(); // get parent of clicked link` second line of the javascript

Comment: @RobinZigmond that did it!!! I have never used `let` before, if you provide an answer with a little explenation I will select it.  I have been messing with this for 2 hours now!

Comment: @chad, thanks for confirming, will do

Comment: Better yet, when you create the `el` variable  to store the parent of the clicked element, you expect that `el` _should **never** change_, so declare it as `const el = ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem appears to be simply that the `el` variable was never formally declared anywhere. Using a variable without declaring it *should* throw an error, and does in "strict mode", but unless you opt in to that (highly recommended), the JS engine will implicitly declare any undeclared variables in the *global* scope.

Tha can cause all manner of nasty problems, but here the particular problem was simply that the three event handler functions were "sharing" the same `el` variable, and therefore overwriting it in the way you observed.

Whereas if you declare it as a local variable instead (this would work just as well with the "old-fashioned" `var` keyword instead, but let's be modern), with `let el = ...`, this problem goes away. `el` is recreated, pointing to the correct element, each time any of the 3 event handlers run, and none can affect the others.

[In fact, as pointed out in other comments/answers, `const` is better here than `let`]

Comment: 50 gold stars!  Thanks for the explanation.  My future JavaScript will be much better.

Answer (score 0):

If you make a new reference to el as a constant. It will fix your issue.

`const myEl = $(this).parent(); // get parent of clicked link`